# What are the lyrics to the Game of Thrones theme?

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones, soundtrack

In S04E10 of *Game of Thrones* as Arya is sailing to Bravos, the show's theme begins to play, only it is accompanied by a choir singing a song. This was quite unusual as we never heard that theme music with actual lyrics throughout the entire show.

So first of all, are these actual words sung or is this just vocal melodization? In the former case, what are those lyrics and how do they relate to the story? Are they based on the books as some of the songs from the TV-show are or were they created for the show itself? Even if they weren't actual words, it would be interesting to know why the choice to provide a vocal accompaniment of the show's theme, something we never had before, was taken for this episode.

Comment: See [an identical question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59668/what-are-the-lyrics-to-the-children-from-game-of-thrones-s04e10) over at sci-fi. Though there doesn't seem to be a definite answer yet, it's a good starting point.

Comment: What would you say about this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYuYIwx7tgE

Comment: I tried to flesh out the question a little more in order to prevent further "trivia" close-votes. Feel free to roll it back if the new question isn't in your interest anymore.

Comment: Pretty sure these are the lyrics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdjEgQbwkOk

Comment: @Drai you know what? That's good enough for me!

Comment: @Drai Could be also [this](https://youtu.be/zs7xO5P3Az4?t=35) ;-)

Comment: Peter Dinklage Peter Dinklage Peter Dinklage Peter Dinklage Peter Dinklage....

Comment: Huh.  I always thought they were simply "Dah, dah, dah-dah-dah, dah, dah-dah-dah..."

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [the final scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT1POpHqjRc)?

The music is called ["The Children"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JYKNqvsbKw) and, like most (if not all) of the GoT music, it was composed by Ramin Djawadi. He was asked a similar question [in a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/27wqjx/i_am_ramin_djawadi_composer_for_game_of_thrones/), and only stated that the choral voices were 'Valyrian-influenced', but gave nothing further. Without anything further, I think we have to assume there are no lyrics available, as there are likely no actual words.

I have heard elsewhere that there is some recognisable Spanish in there, but I don't speak Spanish, so I can't confirm this.

The [Game of Thrones music wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Game_of_Thrones) describes the music thus:

> "The Children": heard when Arya leaves Westeros and sails to Braavos. The track is predominantly a modified choral version of the Main Theme, though it also contains elements of the House Stark theme (Goodbye Brother), and Jaqen H'ghar's theme (Valar Morghulis).

Interestingly, you mention that this is the first time we have heard the Main Theme with choral accompaniment, but there is are precedents in Season 3: ["Dark Wings, Dark Words"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hO_8uwK6l8) and ["Mhysa"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG55MPQjhwo), both of which contain elements of the Main Theme with choral singing.

Comment: In season 8 there is also the song Not Today which has some sort of lyrics, I'm not entirely sure in which scene it plays but from the title I would guess that it also has something to do with Arya. I think she is the only one besides Daenerys who has singing voice in their themes.

Answer (score 2):

There are no lyrics for this track that are publicly available.

The only official confirmation from the composer, Ramin Djawadi, comes from a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/27wqjx/i_am_ramin_djawadi_composer_for_game_of_thrones/), where he reveals that the language of the lyrics is "Valyrian-influenced".

[image: screenshot of relevant comment on the aforelinked Reddit AMA]